# Split path when opening a media in vlc via c# process

Tags: c#, process, vlc

I'm making a WinForm app that let a user to open video through a media player (vlc in the current case). The video path is selected through a openFileDialog control. Here is the code that I use:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe", openFileDialog.FileName);
 }
```

The problem is that this code split file path by space and open each part of path as a file for exemple: The chosen path is `c:\folde1\folder 2\my awesome movie.mp4` So it will treat `c:\folde1\folder` , `2\my` , `awesome`  and `movie.mp4` as seperate files.
How can deal with this issues?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your path in quotes, e.g.:

```
Process.Start(@"""C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe""", openFileDialog.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

that or just write double '\' with out '@' or use / in c#

Comment: @bradbury9 how to do it?

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: escape the arguments variable. If you open msdos console and try it, the same behaviour would happen.

Comment: did you find your problem?

Comment: do you need to opend the vlc a play the movie or you wanna make that your aplication play the video?

Comment: @RosmelTorresAbalo I want to open vlc and play the movie

Comment: look that startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + path_to_video + "\"";
the code will be like that :
[code]{
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.Arguments= "\"" + path + "\"";
 Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe", info.Arguments);
}[/code]

Comment: I hope it wil be helpfull for you

Comment: I'm sorry about the format, if you don't see it clear replay, and I fix it